# AngularJS Code is working in one codepen, but breaks when moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a range slider that is used to filter products. It works perfectly fine in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/RNevYq?editors=101), but when i moved it over to my large scaled product, it won't slide AND it breaks my `count` code on all the `<divs>` below it. Here is the product's [codepen](http://codepen.io/TyStelmach/pen/RNyYmz).

I am using `Rzajac's range slider` which can be found [here](https://github.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider).

HTML

```
  <rzslider
        rz-slider-floor="priceSlider.floor"
        rz-slider-ceil="priceSlider.ceil"
        rz-slider-model="priceSlider.min"
        rz-slider-high="priceSlider.max"
        rz-slider-step="{{priceSlider.step}}"></rzslider>
```

Angular

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['rzModule']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.priceSlider = {
    min: 0,
    max: 20,
    ceil: 20,
    floor: 0,
    step: 1
  };  

$scope.products = [
        {
            name: 'one',
                        height: '00'
                    },
          {
            name: 'two',
                        height: '10'
                    },
          {
            name: 'three',
                        height: '20'
                    }
  ];

  $scope.minFilter = function (p) {
        return p.height >= $scope.priceSlider.min;
    };

   $scope.maxFilter = function (p) {
        return p.height <= $scope.priceSlider.max;
    };
});
```

The slider is located in the "SIZE" tab, thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Angular 1.2.4 in the first Codepen and Angular 1.0.7 in the second. The older Angular is complaining that it doens't understand your directive:

```
Error: Invalid isolate scope definition for directive rzslider: =?
```

Comment: wow, sometimes I just feel so `goddamn` stupid. lol Thanks for the help! I have Angular 1.2.4 in the second one, but only the touch version and I must have missed the 1.0.7 one.

I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: Hey no problem. We all overlook simple things sometimes. Glad to help! :)